# How can I programmatically verify sending emails in AWS SES service?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to verify AWS SES emails programmatically directly from my Nodejs based server. AWS provide a long set of APIs to do all this stuff but I found their APIs quite complicated.

**In simple words:** I want to make a POST or GET request from my Node server to AWS servers to verify email addresses. How can I do it?

I know basic of how to to make requests and get data in JSON format.

Following are some resources that might assist in this case:

- [AWS Verify Email Doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SES.html#verifyEmailAddress-property)
- [AWS Post Request Structure](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/query-interface-requests.html)
- [Request Common Parameters](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/CommonParameters.html)
- [HTTP Requests to Amazon API Gateway](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/making-http-requests/)
- [VerifyEmailAddress Request Parameters](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_VerifyEmailAddress.html)
- [Query Requests and Amazon SES](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/query-interface-requests.html)

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking.  Your first link gives you exactly what you need in order to do this with the node SDK.  Are you saying you don't want to use the SDK, but instead you want to write your own library to do it?  Also I should confirm that you understand what it means to [verify an email address in SES](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-email-addresses.html) -- this is for verifying senders, not recipients.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I'm not able to understand the API documentation. How to get the data and from which API link and what type data and format will I get? The doc is quite complex for me. Can you write a node based small code snippet of verifying email as an example?

Comment: You only need the first link, and the Node SDK.  You don't need any of the other information.  `ses.verifyEmailAddress(params, function(err, data) { ...` as shown right there does all the work.  It is very simple.

Comment: Do I require any NPM module for it? Or any link to send my request? how is my server and AWS connected? And a connection is needed to exchange data.